# how to set odoo domain filter for a field based on user group?

Tags: python, python-3.x, filter, odoo

I'm trying to set to a domain on a field for specific Group and to be open for others to return all values

here what i did

```
def _visit_domain(self):
    domain = []
    if self.env.user.has_group('sales_team.group_sale_salesman'):
        print("Hiiii")

        domain.append(('user_id.name','=',self.user_id.name))
        return domain
    else:
        domain.append(())
        return domain
user_id = fields.Many2one('res.users', string='Salesperson', default=lambda self: self.env.user)
visit_id = fields.Many2one('crm.visit', 'Visit',domain=_visit_domain )
```

it  always return nothing and it's not print HII ever

Comment: I think you should remove line ```domain.append(())```

Answer (score 2):

Why even using a group condition? I would just use a fixed domain on `visit_id`: `"[('user_id', '=?', user_id)]"`. This domain should lead to find only visits of the same user as in your model's `user_id` OR if no `user_id` is given to ALL visits.

If you **also** want to restrict the model `crm.visit` by groups (like in model `sale.order`) use the access utilities of Odoo (`ir.rule`).

Answer (score 1):

Try this
if you want to add "sales_team.group_sale_salesman" in domain of visit_id field i think this solution maybe fit your case..
`visit_id = fields.Many2one('crm.visit', 'Visit',domain= lambda self: [("groups_id", "=", self.env.ref("sales_team.group_sale_salesman").id)] )`

Comment: that would only work if there is a field `groups_id` on model `crm.visit`, which is nowhere said, as far as i can see. So you should probably mention it in your answer.